# test-iq.org problem - rotated, half-colored circles

Tags: visual, progressive-matrix

I am trying to solve this problem from test-iq.org's free demo IQ test. This is the question:
[image]

I did not find out a pattern of how the shapes semicircle moves. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: mccraft123456 this question has nothing to do with how the semicircles move

Comment: I can do look at my answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like

> each row and column has:
>  - one ─ with the top colored
>  - one ╱ with the top-left colored, and
>  - one │ with the left colored.
>  Also, each time, one of the colors is dark blue, one is light blue, and one is white. So the missing shape is a horizontally-divided circle with a light blue top half, which is D.

Comment: Deusovi, but a light blue horizontally-divided circle can also be B, as B is also a light blue horizontally-divided circle.

Comment: @pilotjoker999 Good point! I saw that ambiguity it but figured it was obvious how to clear it up -- it's probably better to be explicit though.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a more water tight anwer:

> The solution is D and this is because that there are 3 original shapes: the one in the top right, bottom middle and middle right. Now the rule is that each of these shapes within the matrix will rotate twice clockwise and each time at a 45 degree angle and each time it does so it will produce a new shape, resulting in two more shapes. The only one in the matrix that has only done it once is top left producing only one shape, and so the solution is of it doing it twice is D.

For those who still cannot follow me:

> If we number the tiles from 1-9, left to right top to bottom the sequence goes where each the shape in each number, where in each consecutive number the shape rotates 45 degrees clockwise:

> 8 - 3 - 4

> 6 -7 - 2

> 1 - 5 - 9(the answer)

Comment: I think this is answer explains the ambiguities the best.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is:

> D

Because:

> Horizontally, on the first row, we can see that in the circles, there is one horizontal line, one vertical line and one tilted line. The same goes for the second row. In the third row, the horizontal line is missing, leaving us with options A, B and D as possible answers. Looking horizontally, on each row, we can see that there is one light blue semicircle, one blue semicircle, and one colourless semicircle in the circles. In the third row where the question mark is, the light blue semicircle is missing, leaving us with options B and D as possible answers. We can also see that when the line in the circle is horizontal, the coloured semicircle is on the top of the line. This leaves us with option D as the answer.

Comment: I think this is a better answer than Deusovi's, since this explains why B cannot be the answer, and Deusovi's doesn't explain that.

Comment: @mccraft123456 Deusovi has changed his answer to a better one. I think his one is clearer than mine.